# UIPageViewController change duration

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

How set faster page turns in UIPageViewController (when tap on edge current page)?

Comment: You want the actual animation of the "page-turning" to be faster?

Comment: I want leave animation "UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl" but just make it faster

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an easy way to do it with the standard `UIPageViewController`, the trick is to simply set the UIView animation of the frame to be shorter, but you would have to implement this behavior in your custom PageView Controller.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Apple's class documentation for UIPageViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html) it's only possible to change the style for animation, not the speed.